# add Section into tableView using values from an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, struct

i have an array which haves some values in this `["April : 2016   : P 2  : A 28"]` pattern , i want to add the year which is `2016` here , as an section so that i can have a tableView like :

```
2016
April : 2016   : P 92  : A 528
March : 2016   : P 42  : A 128
May : 2016   : P 12  : A 238
June : 2016   : P 23  : A 268

2017
Jan : 2016   : P 92  : A 528
April : 2016   : P 42  : A 128
Dec : 2016   : P 12  : A 238
Oct : 2016   : P 23  : A 268
```

how am gonna do that i tired this

i created a struct

```
    struct  datesStruct {
    var sectionYear : String!
    var sectionMonth : [String]!
}

        for set in setOfMonths {

        datesStructArray.append(datesStruct(sectionYear: "\(yearInt)", sectionMonth: newArrayofValues))
    // here `yearInt` is the year which have to be my section for records and i pulled it from the `newArrayofValues` array
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

in output there's no section even now i have duplicated record on my table ? 
any idea how can i add section using a value  from a record which looks like this `["April : 2016   : P 2  : A 28"]`   any help would be much appreciated

update:

now am getting section but sections are repeating (duplicate entry of same section) is my code:

```
    for set in setOfMonths {

     datesStructArray.append(datesStruct(sectionYear: "\(yearInt)", sectionMonth: newArrayofValues)) //  here newArrayOfValue is an array
    tableView.reloadData()
      }
```

my output:

```
2016
Jan : 2016   : P 92  : A 528
2016
April : 2016   : P 42  : A 128
2016
Dec : 2016   : P 12  : A 238
2017
Oct : 2017   : P 23  : A 268
```

but what i want is :

```
2016
Jan : 2016   : P 92  : A 528
April : 2016   : P 42  : A 128
Dec : 2016   : P 12  : A 238

2017
Oct : 2017   : P 23  : A 268
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, you will need to maintain the data as a dictionary. Key being the year, and the values being an array of string objects.

For example-

```
var dataDict = ["2017" : ["April : 2016   : P 92  : A 528", 
                          "March : 2016   : P 42  : A 128"],

                "2016" : ["Jan : 2016   : P 92  : A 528", 
                          "Feb : 2016   : P 42  : A 128"]]
```

Now you can return number of sections in the data source method as:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    return dataDict.keys.count
}
```

You will need to maintain a sorted list of the section names, and supply them as section titles:

```
let sortedSectionNames = dataDict.keys.sort()
```

You pass the section titles in the following data source method-

```
 func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> [String]?{
    return sortedSectionNames
}
```

Now you need to return the configured cells for rows for sections:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Dequeue the cell...

    //Get the appropriate model-
    let section = indexPath.section
    let dataArray = dataDict[sortedSectionNames[section]]!
    let stringForRow = dataArray[indexPath.row]

    //Set this string into a label in your cell...
}
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot ! for your effort i really appreciate it and i think this is what i need but can you take a look on my updated question ? because i  think i came too long and am about to get my solution

Comment: hey @shripada i tried according to  your answer but the output is showing only a single section and column  ?? any idea whats wrong should i show you my code ??

Comment: dataDict.keys.count is returning 1 , know why ?

Comment: thanks bro i found another way thanks for helping , appreciate you